# Regex только цифры и в конце знак `\$?$`

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Есть такая регулярка.

```
(^[1-9]*)([0-9]?)(.{1}?)([0-9]{1,})\$?$
```

Оно должна вычислить цифры и в конце знак доллара, который может и не быть.

У нее одна проблема, после знака доллара если написать цифры она берет этот результат то же.

Подскажите как решить эту проблему?

Вот [линк](https://regex101.com/r/QmdbUg/1) для проверки.

Надо что бы регулярка брала строки таких типов

```
4564
45689$
4564.4564
4564846.456$
```

А такие нет.

```
456415$45646
```

Comment: Ничего непонятно. Где желаемый результат?

Comment: @Qwertiy Изменил вопрос.

Comment: `^[1-9][0-9]*(?:\.[0-9]+)?\$?$`? [Демо](https://regex101.com/r/omhcoP/1).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew супер, спасибо вам.

Comment: @StrangerintheQ протестируйте вот эту строку `000.000$`

Comment: @RazGalstyan а это что-само собой разумеющееся? как это отражено в воросе? или надо было по Вашей регулярке догадаться?

Comment: тоесть 0.50$ это некорректный ввод для Вас?

Comment: @StrangerintheQ Знаете я вам признателен за то что интересовались моим вопросом. Но посмотрите сами. Все ясно без какой либо дополнительной информации.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете использовать

```
^[1-9][0-9]*(?:\.[0-9]+)?\$?$
```

Подробности:

- `^` - начало строки
- `[1-9][0-9]*` - цифра от 1 до 9, а за ней 0 и более любых цифр
- `(?:\.[0-9]+)?` - один или ноль повторов точки и 1 и более цифр
- `\$?` - один или ноль знаков доллара
- `$` - конец строки.

Answer (score 1):

`/^\d*\.?\d+\$?$/`

`^` = в начале строки

`\d*` = любое число цифр (в том числе и 0)

`\.` = точка

`?` = может отсутствовать

`\$` = символ доллара

`$` = в конце строки

```js
test(".01$");
test("t1est");
test("230.01");
test("foo");
test("bar");
test("3049.58$");
test("bar");
test("534.534$23");
test("123");
test("123.");

function test(v){
  console.log(v, v.match(/^\d*\.?\d+\$?$/)?true:false)
}
```

Comment: Есть проблема. вот это не берет `123`

Comment: @RazGalstyan подрихтовал

Comment: Еще один минус. Вот это берет `230.`.

Comment: @RazGalstyan а это некорректно? я специально так сделал =)

Comment: @RazGalstyan заменил * на +

Comment: @RazGalstyan а с первой так же, она обязательна или нет, до точки?

Comment: Первая нормально.